# phpmailer looping through multiple emails [PHP PHPMAILER]

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using the phpmailer and I want to send it to multiple of emails at once, by using for loop. This is my current coding:

```
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;                       
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to         use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'yyy.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'yyy';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
$person = array(0 => 'xxx.com', 'xxx2.com');
for ($x = 0; $x < 2; $x++) {
$mail->addAddress($person[$x]); 
}
$mail->setFrom('yyy.com'); 
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = "xxx";
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Right now, the code works, but, when you check at "TO" at your email client, it also outputs OTHER emails, included alongside - and I don't want that. It's like, when you email to xxx.com, xxx2.com can see at his "TO" field, saying `TO <name1> <xxx.com>, <name2> <xxx2.com>`. How do I avoid that ? Should I create a loop starting from `$mail = new PHPMailer;` ?

Comment: You are just adding an email address to the recipient list before sending. You need to also put ```$mail->send()``` within the loop.

Comment: How should my code looks like now ?

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: Look at [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another possible way without re-creating the Class each time.

```
<?php

require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to         use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'yyy.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'yyy';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
$person = array(0 => 'xxx.com', 'xxx2.com');

$mail->setFrom('yyy.com');
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = "xxx";
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

$errors = [];
for ($x = 0; $x < 2; $x++) {
    $mail->addAddress($person[$x]);
    if(!$mail->send()) {
        $errors[] = 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    $mail->clearAddresses();
}

if(empty($errors)) {
    // success
} else {
    // handle errors
}
```

Using `$mail->clearAddresses();` within the loop.

Comment: `$mail->clearAddresses();` is what I'm looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Better way to add them as Carbon Copy recipients.

```
$mail->AddCC('person1@domain.com', 'Person One');
$mail->AddCC('person2@domain.com', 'Person Two');
// ..
```

To make things easy, you should loop through an array to do this.

```
$recipients = array(
   'person1@domain.com' => 'Person One',
   'person2@domain.com' => 'Person Two',
   // ..
);
foreach($recipients as $email => $name)
{
   $mail->AddCC($email, $name);
}
```

I have not implement this but I think this will work for you.

Comment: BCC would be better - it doesn't expose all recipients addresses to everyone.